# Filtering a column in Excel from C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# program that currently creates it's own excel template every time it's run, I'm wanting to filter the columns from the header e.g. A4 down to the last entity in the A column, and then for B, C etc etc.

I have seen a few solutions however they require selecting the entire column but the sheet has some logos and titles on before it starts getting to the Data.

Example:

A4 is Employee Name, so I want A4 to be where the filter dropdown is, and then A5 onwards are the names of the employees (which can shrink/grow weekly so needs to be dynamic).

All help is appreciated, TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can used the Excel.Range.Select(A5:Asomethinglarge) method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.select

And then the Range.Sort method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort

So something like:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:ASomethinglarge").Select

Range.sort(Key1, Order1)
```

I'm a little rusty so that might be how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the filter option. That automatically sets filters across selected columns.